# Cython optimization of the code

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, cythonize

I'm struggling to boost the performance of my python particle tracking code with Cython.

Here's my pure Python code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, pi, sin, cos
from time import time as Time
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

cLight = 299792458.
Dim = 6

class Integrator:
    def __init__(self, ring):
        self.ring = ring

    def equations(self, X, s):
        dXds = np.zeros(Dim)

        E, B = self.ring.getEMField( [X[0], X[2], s], X[4] )

        h = 1 + X[0]/self.ring.ringRadius
        p_s = np.sqrt(X[5]**2 - self.ring.particle.mass**2 - X[1]**2 - X[3]**2)
        dtds = h*X[5]/p_s
        gamma = X[5]/self.ring.particle.mass
        beta = np.array( [X[1], X[3], p_s] ) / X[5]

        dXds[0] = dtds*beta[0]
        dXds[2] = dtds*beta[1]
        dXds[1] = p_s/self.ring.ringRadius + self.ring.particle.charge*(dtds*E[0] + dXds[2]*B[2] - h*B[1])
        dXds[3] = self.ring.particle.charge*(dtds*E[1] + h*B[0] - dXds[0]*B[2])
        dXds[4] = dtds
        dXds[5] = self.ring.particle.charge*(dXds[0]*E[0] + dXds[2]*E[1] + h*E[2])
        return dXds

    def odeSolve(self, X0, sRange):
        sol = odeint(self.equations, X0, sRange)
        return sol

class Ring:
    def __init__(self, particle):
        self.particle = particle
        self.ringRadius = 7.112
        self.magicB0 = self.particle.magicMomentum/self.ringRadius

    def getEMField(self, pos, time):
        x, y, s = pos
        theta = (s/self.ringRadius*180/pi) % 360
        r = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        arg = 0 if r == 0 else np.angle( complex(x/r, y/r) )
        rn = r/0.045

        k2 = 37*24e3
        k10 = -4*24e3

        E = np.zeros(3)
        B = np.array( [ 0, self.magicB0, 0 ] )

        for i in range(4):
            if ((21.9+90*i < theta < 34.9+90*i or 38.9+90*i < theta < 64.9+90*i) and (-0.05 < x < 0.05 and -0.05 < y < 0.05)):
                E = np.array( [ k2*x/0.045 + k10*rn**9*cos(9*arg), -k2*y/0.045 -k10*rn**9*sin(9*arg), 0] )
                break
        return E, B

class Particle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mass = 105.65837e6
        self.charge = 1.
        self.gm2 = 0.001165921 

        self.magicMomentum = self.mass/sqrt(self.gm2)
        self.magicEnergy = sqrt(self.magicMomentum**2 + self.mass**2)
        self.magicGamma = self.magicEnergy/self.mass
        self.magicBeta = self.magicMomentum/(self.magicGamma*self.mass)


def runSimulation(nParticles, tEnd):
    particle = Particle()
    ring = Ring(particle)
    integrator = Integrator(ring)

    Xs = np.array( [ np.array( [45e-3*(np.random.rand()-0.5)*2, 0, 0, 0, 0, particle.magicEnergy] ) for i in range(nParticles) ] )
    sRange = np.arange(0, tEnd, 1e-9)*particle.magicBeta*cLight 

    ode = partial(integrator.odeSolve, sRange=sRange)

    t1 = Time()

    pool = mp.Pool()
    sol = np.array(pool.map(ode, Xs))

    t2 = Time()
    print ("%.3f sec" %(t2-t1))

    return t2-t1
```

Obviously, the most time-consuming process is integrating the ODE, defined as odeSolve() and equations() in class Integrator. Also, getEMField() method in class Ring is called as much as equations() method during the solving process.
I tried to get significant amount of speed up (at least 10x~20x) using Cython, but I only got ~1.5x level of speed up by the following Cython script:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt, pi, sin, cos

from scipy.integrate import odeint
from time import time as Time
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

cdef double cLight = 299792458.
cdef int Dim = 6

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef class Integrator:
    cdef Ring ring

    def __init__(self, ring):
        self.ring = ring

    cpdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] equations(self,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] X,
                  double s):
        cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] dXds = np.zeros(Dim)
        cdef double h, p_s, dtds, gamma
        cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] beta, E, B

        E, B = self.ring.getEMField( [X[0], X[2], s], X[4] )

        h = 1 + X[0]/self.ring.ringRadius
        p_s = np.sqrt(X[5]*X[5] - self.ring.particle.mass*self.ring.particle.mass - X[1]*X[1] - X[3]*X[3])
        dtds = h*X[5]/p_s
        gamma = X[5]/self.ring.particle.mass
        beta = np.array( [X[1], X[3], p_s] ) / X[5]

        dXds[0] = dtds*beta[0]
        dXds[2] = dtds*beta[1]
        dXds[1] = p_s/self.ring.ringRadius + self.ring.particle.charge*(dtds*E[0] + dXds[2]*B[2] - h*B[1])
        dXds[3] = self.ring.particle.charge*(dtds*E[1] + h*B[0] - dXds[0]*B[2])
        dXds[4] = dtds
        dXds[5] = self.ring.particle.charge*(dXds[0]*E[0] + dXds[2]*E[1] + h*E[2])
        return dXds

    cpdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] odeSolve(self,
                 np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] X0,
                 np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] sRange):
        sol = odeint(self.equations, X0, sRange)
        return sol

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef class Ring:
    cdef Particle particle
    cdef double ringRadius
    cdef double magicB0

    def __init__(self, particle):
        self.particle = particle
        self.ringRadius = 7.112
        self.magicB0 = self.particle.magicMomentum/self.ringRadius

    cpdef tuple getEMField(self,
                   list pos,
                   double time):
        cdef double x, y, s
        cdef double theta, r, rn, arg, k2, k10
        cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, negative_indices=False, mode="c"] E, B

        x, y, s = pos
        theta = (s/self.ringRadius*180/pi) % 360
        r = sqrt(x*x + y*y)
        arg = 0 if r == 0 else np.angle( complex(x/r, y/r) )
        rn = r/0.045

        k2 = 37*24e3
        k10 = -4*24e3

        E = np.zeros(3)
        B = np.array( [ 0, self.magicB0, 0 ] )

        for i in range(4):
            if ((21.9+90*i < theta < 34.9+90*i or 38.9+90*i < theta < 64.9+90*i) and (-0.05 < x < 0.05 and -0.05 < y < 0.05)):
                E = np.array( [ k2*x/0.045 + k10*rn**9*cos(9*arg), -k2*y/0.045 -k10*rn**9*sin(9*arg), 0] )
                #E = np.array( [ k2*x/0.045, -k2*y/0.045, 0] )
                break
        return E, B

cdef class Particle:
    cdef double mass
    cdef double charge
    cdef double gm2

    cdef double magicMomentum
    cdef double magicEnergy
    cdef double magicGamma
    cdef double magicBeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.mass = 105.65837e6
        self.charge = 1.
        self.gm2 = 0.001165921 

        self.magicMomentum = self.mass/sqrt(self.gm2)
        self.magicEnergy = sqrt(self.magicMomentum**2 + self.mass**2)
        self.magicGamma = self.magicEnergy/self.mass
        self.magicBeta = self.magicMomentum/(self.magicGamma*self.mass)

def runSimulation(nParticles, tEnd):
    particle = Particle()
    ring = Ring(particle)
    integrator = Integrator(ring)

    #nParticles = 5
    Xs = np.array( [ np.array( [45e-3*(np.random.rand()-0.5)*2, 0, 0, 0, 0, particle.magicEnergy] ) for i in range(nParticles) ] )
    sRange = np.arange(0, tEnd, 1e-9)*particle.magicBeta*cLight 

    ode = partial(integrator.odeSolve, sRange=sRange)

    t1 = Time()

    pool = mp.Pool()
    sol = np.array(pool.map(ode, Xs))

    t2 = Time()
    print ("%.3f sec" %(t2-t1))

    return t2-t1
```

What should I do to get the maximum effect from Cython?
(I tried Numba instead of Cython, and actually the performance gain from Numba was enormous (around ~20x speedup). But I had extremely hard time to utilize Numba with python class instances, and I decided to use Cython instead of Numba).

For reference, the following is cython annotation on its compilation:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you benchmarked your code to find the bottlenecks? From a quick read-through, it's not immediately obvious to me that Cython or Numba will be able to provide much speedup at all: most of your operations are already being done in a vectorized manner. I'd start by using a [line profiler](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html#Line-By-Line-Profiling-with-%lprun) to figure out where the slow spots are.

Comment: @jakevdp Thank you for your comment. I looked up to use line profiler, but it seems I first need to learn how to use it on Cython and Python3... It takes some time. In case it will help, I added the result of Cython compilation with annotation mode.

Comment: I think he recommend to use line profiler on your original / non-cython code to see which operations are slow. If those are basic numpy-primitives / vectorized parts, you know that cython is not going to help.

Comment: You will probably use all the time in odeint? The best option would be to do multiprocessing? The rest will be quite quick I presume?

Comment: Yes, I would s suggest profiling your Python code before translating it to Cython. I suspect the bottlenecks are in places where cython & numba will be of limited help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very incomplete answer since I haven't profiled or timed anything or even checked that it gives the same answer. However here are some suggestions that reduce the amount of Python code that Cython generates:

- Add the `@cython.cdivision(True)` compilation directive. This means that a `ZeroDivisionError` won't be raised on float division and you'll get a `NaN` value instead. (Only do this if you don't want the error to be raised).
- Change `p_s = np.sqrt(...)` to `p_s = sqrt(...)`. This removes a numpy call that only operates on a single value. You seem to have done this elsewhere so I don't know why you missed this line.
- Where possible use fixed size C arrays instead of numpy arrays:

  ```
  cdef double beta[3]
  # ...
  beta[0] = X[1]/X[5]
  beta[1] = X[3]/X[5]
  beta[2] = p_s/X[5]
  ```

  You can do this when the size is known at compile time (and fairly small) and when you don't want to return it. This avoids a call to `np.zeros` and some subsequent type-checking to assign it the the typed numpy array. I think `beta` is the only place you can do this.
- `np.angle( complex(x/r, y/r) )` can be replaced by `atan2(y/r, x/r)` (using `atan2` from `libc.math`. You can also lose the division by `r`
- `cdef int i` helps make your `for` loop faster in `getEMField` (Cython is often good at automatically picking up the types of loop variables but seems to have failed here)
- I suspect it's quicker to assign `E` element-by-element than as a whole array:

  ```
          E[0] = k2*x/0.045 + k10*rn**9*cos(9*arg)
          E[1] = -k2*y/0.045 -k10*rn**9*sin(9*arg)
  ```
- There isn't much value in specifying types like `list` and `tuple` and it may actually make the code slightly slower (because it will waste time checking the types).
- A bigger change would be to pass `E` and `B` into `GetEMField` as pointers rather than using allocating them `np.zeros`. This would let you allocate them as static C arrays in `equations` (`cdef double E[3]`). The downside is that `GetEMField` would have to be `cdef` so no longer callable from Python (but you could make a Python callable wrapper function too if you like).